# Drag and drop on React with an error "t..drop is not a function at content"

Tags: reactjs, drag, drop

When I use "e.preventDefault()" it makes an arror in the console with drop one element on another one.
When I don't write "e.preventDefault()" there are no errors but my DragAndDrop doesn't work.

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.drop is not a function
    at content.js:1:38480
    at Object.handleEvent (content.js:1:41982)
(
```

```
export default function Dashboard() {

    const dragOverHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return (

        <div>
            <div id='1' draggable={true}
                onDragOver={(e) => dragOverHandler(e)}
            >one element
            </div>
            <div id='2' draggable={true}
                onDragOver={(e) => dragOverHandler(e)}
            >another element
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Everithing works well but I can'n rid the error

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: @Peter the code doesn't show the image error, show the scope of the code where you are calling `t.drop` and everything about where it's value is coming from & what u expect it to be.

Comment: I've edited my question you to be able to copy it and get the same error